# Option NSKeyValueObservingOptions.initial in block-based KVO

Tags: swift5, key-value-observing, ios13.4

The documentation says [when `.initial` is used]: *The change dictionary in the notification will always contain an newKey entry if new is also specified but will never contain an oldKey entry.*

In block-based KVO observer receives `change` struct, where `oldValue` is used.

`oldValue` has wild type `Optional<Optional<Any>>`.

Any forms of direct comparison (with nil, .some(nil) etc) are failed because of "Any is not Comparable" error.

How can I check that the call of observer is initial?

**UPDATE**

Well.

I'm observing a `value: Any` from some `attribute`. Really `value` is constructed from binary data inside the `attribute` and has the type in which it was delivered, the real type is `Bool?` in this case. Observer is fired correctly, it is not the problem.

```
observe(\ViewController.attribute.value, options: [.initial, .new, .old]) { (_self, change) in
    guard change.newValue as? Bool != change.oldValue as? Bool // does not work in initial
    else { 
        return 
    }
    ...
}
```

In initial case I have

```
(lldb) po change
▿ NSKeyValueObservedChange<Optional<Any>>
  - kind : __C.NSKeyValueChange
  ▿ newValue : Optional<Optional<Any>>
    ▿ some : Optional<Any>
      - some : <null>
  ▿ oldValue : Optional<Optional<Any>>
    - some : nil
  - indexes : nil
  - isPrior : false
```

New value is `nil` (`attribute.value == .none`). Old value, in accordance with documentation, must be not contained. What should I do to ensure that it is not contained really?

Comment: Can you post your code, so we can try and solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I found:

```
guard
    case let oldValue? = change.oldValue, oldValue == nil ||
    (change.newValue as? Bool != oldValue as? Bool)
else
{
    return
}
```